# my SELECT COUNT query returns an array not an integer

Tags: php, mysql, select, count

I've looked at other similar questions on Stacked and even used an example, which I will post below that says it should return an integer but I still get an array...

So.. How come I'm getting an array and how do I get an integer instead?

```
function user_exists($username){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(username) FROM logins");

    // Verify it worked
    if (!$result) echo mysql_error();

    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    // Should show you an integer result.
    print_r($row);


    }
```

This outputs: "Array ( [0] => 1 )". The comment says it should be an integer.
Any help greatly appreciated!

The above code was for test purposes only, Iam actually trying to test the value of a SELECT COUNT and return it a true (or false) boolean  in a function:

```
function user_exists($username){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT (username) FROM `logins` WHERE `username`='$username'");
    return (mysql_result($query, 0)==1) ? true: false;
    }
```

but the $query var is an array not a single value

Comment: Also, you really should be migrating over to the PDO object. Much safer to use when accessing MySQL.

Comment: @Fluffeh Excellent point (I was just about to comment). @gavin - See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php))? The `mysql_*` functions are being deprecated. There is absolutely no reason why you should use them for new code. Switch to prepared statements and [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) instead.

Comment: @Fluffeh, Ricardo Altamirano: it becomes annoying, really

Comment: @zerkms Sorry, what is annoying?

Comment: @Fluffeh: mentioning pdo/mysqli in every php&mysql-related question (even 100% irrelevant to the parameters binding and prepared statements. In this particular case **there is no difference** between `mysql_` and pdo/mysqli)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that, for sure. I'd like to get it to work with these functions first though, so I can understand it. then I'll certainly investigate the PDO

Comment: @zerkms I really enjoy your sour demeanor in comments - they give me a good smirk more often than not, but surely if the chap is using mysql_* functions here, he will be using them everywhere else in his code. I can assure you that I am as annoyed constantly seeing folks using depreciated functions, but know that they are likely following a tutorial on some old website that hasn't been updated in years - surely a comment pointing them in the right direction isn't a bad thing?

Comment: @gavin: should it be `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logins WHERE username='$username'"` instead?

Comment: Yes, sorry - updated. It fell out, somehow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It returns a row with one column, use `$row[0]` to get the value form the first column.

As implied by the function name, `mysql_fetch_row` is expected to return a row, in the form of an array with an element for each column in the result set.

From [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php):

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns an numerical array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows.
>
> mysql_fetch_row() fetches one row of data from the result associated with the specified result identifier. The row is returned as an array. Each result column is stored in an array offset, starting at offset 0.

As commented by Ricardo and Fluffeh, this interface is deprecated and you should use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).  Before PDO, PHP lacked an unified interface to databases, and it was really hard to switch databases in a project. Using PDO makes easy to support multiple databases, and [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) makes your code more secure against SQL injection attacks.

[update]

> Thanks, perhaps the mysql_row is not the best method, I only used it for test purposes. I am actually trying to insert the result into a mysql_result, as a number but it is an array, so I believe the SELECT COUNT returns an array originally, when I thought it was meant to return an integer. really I want the $result=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT") to be a single value.. Hmmmm..?

If you really want to fetch the value as an integer, you can use this instead:

```
// $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$row = mysql_result($result, 0, 0); // first row, first column
```

Comment: Thanks, perhaps the mysql_row is not the best method, I only used it for test purposes. I am actually trying to insert the result into a mysql_result, as a number but it is an array, so I believe the SELECT COUNT returns an array originally, when I thought it was meant to return an integer. really I want the $result=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT") to be a single value.. Hmmmm..?

Comment: You can use `mysql_result($result, 0, 0)` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out. One question, though - is SELECT COUNT not meant to return a single value anyway? Everywhere I read, it says so but in my example it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: @gavin: this query returns a single row and column indeed, but a result set is always rows and columns, even if the result is 1 X 1 like in this case. BTW, would you mark my answer as accepted now?